# Custom subscription to SharePoint list items

Tags: 2013, list, alert, subscriptions

I want to create subscription/alerting system on list items by enabling user to choose which item(s) he/she wants to track.

Couple of things to mention, there are three main columns:

1. Project
2. Milestone
3. Task

Project and Milestone are lookup columns (cascade drop down) and Task is single line of text.
If user chooses to track (gets alert on item change or whatever) Milestone, than all Tasks that are children of a chosen Milestone should be included in tracking, with possibility of user to uncheck tasks by his will. Same goes for Project, if he chooses to track Project, than all Milestones (and with them Tasks) of that project should be checked for subscription.

Any suggestion how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you'll find a way to do it with the functionality out of the box. In the past I have developed several alarm systems and I always use this approach:

1) Create a C # program that performs queries with CAML on SharePoint lists.

2) Schedule a daily task to send alerts

3) Program some configuration page if required.

In principle there are two variants.

**SSOM**

If you have access to the server object model it is always better. You create the program and a SharePoint TimerJob to run daily.

**CSOM**

If you can not use the server object model. You can create a C # console application that accesses SharePoint using Client Object Model. Then you run the program from the windows programs tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I forgot to mention that we are not allowed to use visual studio as we don't have licenses. I can only use SPD and SP itself.

Comment: You do not need visual studio for CSOM. It is only javascript.